# PQC schemes & theory on academic courses

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, education

This question doesn't cover any technical aspects of PQC but I would want to know if undergraduate computer scientists study at a good level any of the available PQC schemes in literature during their stance at university in whatever country you know.

Don't get my wrong, in the country where I live there is no PhD on Cryptography perse. There are masters on Cybersecurity that cover the basics of Information Theory combined with classic Cryptography but these are not deep enough to grasp the technical math behind these fields.

In my case, I'm a self-taught individual and asking questions related to PQC or non-classicak crypto on the institution where I used to attend never had an answer. With time, effort and patience I was able to learn part of the math behind.

I'd like to read your experiences through academic education and how did you discover and start researching on PQC. It'd be great if you can specify the country where this happened.

#### Questions:

Was it once after the master or PhD ended?

Should PQC be taught to normal students when dealing with Cryptography for the sake of the future?

Would you change the way Cryptography is taught to students to include new topics that will be mainstream in few decades?

P.D : Feel free to vote to close if this post doesn't fit the site's rules. I found the education and theory tag to fulfill the requirements, but maybe do not.

Comment: I'm at a university with quite the heavy focus on Cryptography (we have like 5 crypto-focused research groups). We had one lecture series / module on the technical details of PQ Crypto (which apparently also mostly covered hash-based signature schemes like XMSS and maybe SPHINCS and lattice crypto), the relevant professor has left now. I think the most PQ crypto you'll see here outside of this lecture is Hash-based One-Time Signatures and maybe one lecture session giving you a rough intuition on how PQ crypto and their hard problems work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience SEJPM. Introducing PQC problems may be seem enough to motivate the attendee to pursue research in these topics. Having 5 groups strongly dedicated to crypto seems like a good environment to work in, due to the benefit of sharing ideas, combining work with colleagues and improving the understanding of topics by learning from your surroundings.